# Stream straight from mgo result to json without unserializing to struct in go

Tags: json, mongodb, go

is there a way to go straight from an mgo result to a JSON byte array without having to serialize to a slice of structs first?

Answer (score 1):

Decode the result to an `interface{}`.  Encode the `interface{}` as JSON.

```
var v interface{}
if err := c.Find(query).One(&v); err != nil {
   // handle error
}
p, err := json.Marshal(v)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}

// p is []byte containing the JSON
```

Answer (score 1):

The method [One()](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query.One) according with the documentation: *executes the query and unmarshals the first obtained document into the result argument*, so it's doing the Marshal anyways, but we can "trick" it using the type [json.RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) that is just a slice of bytes and it's in the std library.

```
var result json.RawMessage

if err := c.Find(query).One(&result); err != nil { ... }
```

There's a full example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/IR1_O87SHv) about RawMessage.

Comment: thanks, this seems slower than putting it into a struct, I thought it would have been faster.